# in_array function is not giving expected results

Tags: php, arrays, newline

I am using `in_array` to search in an array if a value exists. My code is below:

```
$file = 'domains.txt'; //reading txt file
$lines = file($file);//file in to an array

if (in_array("yahoo.com", $lines)) {
    echo "Got Domain";
}
```

However, its not working, it only displays a blank page, but yahoo.com is available in domains.txt so it should return true, but i am stuck with it, please help, thanks.

Comment: You have no error checking to determine whether or not you read anything from the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` flag when calling [`file()`](http://php.net/file):

```
$lines = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

When the line with yahoo.com is being read, it is being stored as:

```
"yahoo.com\n"
```

The above flag will tells [`file()`](http://php.net/file) not to append the newline (`\n`) character to each string in the returned array.

Comment: that worked, can you please let me know why did we use `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` and what were i am missing?

Comment: `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` removes the newline character `\n` at the end (which occurs to be at every new single line, *oh wonder*) :)

Comment: Don't forget about the case-sensitivity of in_array